# gatsby-node.js multiple api calls

Tags: reactjs, rest, gatsby

I'm having issues loading multiple nodes from different API calls. Each individual node-type works fine, but gatsby-node.js allows only one type to be set, so all CreateNode work should be done in one go. I can't figure out if it's not working because of the multi async calls, or something else ...

I have tried many different methods, the one below is the latest experiment, but all of them have failed.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');

exports.sourceNodes = async ({ actions }) => {
    const { createNode } = actions;

    const fetchUsers = () => axios.get('http://192.168.0.71/api/manager/users/user/', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXX',
        },
    }).then(res => {
        const hUsers = Object.keys(res.data).map((row,i) => {
            const userNode = {
                id: res.data[row].id,
                parent: null,
                internal: {
                    type: 'HomeyUsers',
                },
                children: [],
                email: res.data[row].email,
                name: res.data[row].name,
                properties: res.data[row].properties,
                enabled: res.data[row].enabled,
                verified: res.data[row].verified,
                picture: res.data[row].avatar,
                role:   res.data[row].role,
                present: res.data[row].present,
                asleep: res.data[row].asleep,
                inviteUrl: res.data[row].inviteURL,
                inviteToken: res.data[row].inviteToken
            };
            const contentDigest = crypto
                .createHash('md5')
                .update(JSON.stringify(userNode))
                .digest('hex');
            userNode.internal.contentDigest = contentDigest;
            createNode(userNode);
        });
    });

    const fetchDevices = () => axios.get('http://192.168.0.71/api/manager/devices/device/',{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXX',
        },
    }).then(res => {
        //const res = await fetchDevices();
        const hDevices = Object.keys(res.data).map((row,i) => {
            const deviceNode = {
                id: res.data[row].id,
                parent: null,
                internal: {
                    type: 'HomeyDevices',
                },
                children: [],
                name: res.data[row].name,
                zone: res.data[row].zone
            };
            const contentDigest = crypto
                .createHash('md5')
                .update(JSON.stringify(deviceNode))
                .digest('hex');
            deviceNode.internal.contentDigest = contentDigest;
            createNode(deviceNode);
        });
    }); 

    const fetchFlows = () => axios.get('http://192.168.0.71/api/manager/flow/flow/',{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXX',
        },
        }).then(res => {
            //const res = await fetchFlows();
            const hFlows = Object.keys(res.data).map((row,i) => {
                const flowNode = {
                    id: res.data[row].id,
                    parent: '__SOURCE__',
                    internal: {
                        type: 'HomeyFlows', 
                    },
                    children: [],
                    name: res.data[row].name,
                    folder: res.data[row].folder,
                    enabled: res.data[row].enabled,
                    actions: res.data[row].actions,
                };
            const contentDigest = crypto
                .createHash('md5')
                .update(JSON.stringify(flowNode))
                .digest('hex');
            flowNode.internal.contentDigest = contentDigest;
            createNode(flowNode);
        });
    });

    return Promise.all([hUsers, hDevices, hFlows]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Jan.   Welcome to Stackoverflow.  "all of them have failed" is rather broad.  Can you let us know what errors or issues your are encountering?

Comment: Hi @Dijkgraaf, the issues is that either the command "npm run develop" does not start the development server because of an error. And if it does start, the GraphQL site does not list my Nodes. So the errors and issues i'm hitting have to do with way that the combined method is not working ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code defined 3 functions that return promises:

```
const fetchUsers = () => axios.get(...)
const fetchDevices = () => axios.get(...)
const fetchFlows = () => axios.get(...)
```

But you didn’t call them anywhere. `Promise.all` expected an array of promises, but you passed in 3 variables that weren't defined in the same scope

```
return Promise.all([hUsers, hDevices, hFlows]);
```

Perhaps this will take you a bit further:

```
return Promise.all([fetchUsers(), fetchDevices(), fetchFlows()]);
```

---

If it still doesn't work, the first thing you should share on SO is your error messages — it'll be tremendously helpful to others! Gatsby throws a lot of stuff into the console, so you'd have to watch it for anything that's red, or seems unusual.

Comment: After reading your comments, it all makes sense. I was really stuck on the build-up of the promises. Now I can see it is the "const fetchUsers" that contains the output of the API query.